# Single and Double Quotes are converted into some junk characters when text is fetched and displayed from XML file

Tags: php, html, xml

I am having below strange issue related to HTML and XML. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Example Text: it’s “not displaying” fine.

This is output when printed directly on page using either HTML or PHP : it’s “not displaying” fine.

This is output when fetched & printed from generated XML file : it�s �not displaying�� fine.

XML file contains this declaration : `<? xml version= 1.0 encoding= iso-8859-1 ?>`

When I try to use `utf-8` instead of `iso-8859-1` in above XML file declaration then text is not displaying on web page.

EDIT#1 : Below is the code used to display data from XML file.

```
$result_test="";
$result_test=readXml($XML_FILE_PATH."test.xml",$XML_ROOT);
<?php
$arr_test=array_keys($result_test);
if($arr_test[0]!="XML_ROOT") { ?>
    <?php 
    while(list($key, $val) = each($result_test)) {
        if(is_array($val)) { ?>
        <div><?php print($result_test[$key]["DESC"]);?>/div>
    <?php } } ?>
```

EDIT# 2 : Below is XML file's data. Square shape junk character is displaying instead of single and double quote in .xml file but when I put that char here, it is removed so could not show you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XML_ROOT>
<P_1>
    <DESC><![CDATA[its not displaying fine.]]</DESC>
</P_1>
</XML_ROOT>
```

Comment: Any code to go with your explanation cause we don't know what you did wrong.

Comment: Elaborate the question and mention how you're fetching and printing. That's the most relevant part in the question and it's missing.

Comment: @xRahul, please allow me few minutes to put that code. I agree with you.

Comment: @xRahul, I just added the code for reference.

Comment: @Ahm23,  I just added the code for reference.

Comment: Please provide an example file.

Comment: @DanielO. I added .xml file code in my question as EDIT#2. Please check and provide your feedback.

Comment: `readXml` is not a pre defined function. You need to put the implementation of it here.

Answer (score 1):

1) The CDATA section is invalid (missing `>`)

Format: `<![CDATA[my data]]>`

2) Example how to read and convert the value from ISO to UTF-8:

```
$source = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XML_ROOT>
<P_1>
    <DESC><![CDATA[its not displaying fine.]]></DESC>
</P_1>
</XML_ROOT>';

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$dom->loadXML($source);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$desc = $xpath->query('/XML_ROOT/P_1/DESC')->item(0)->nodeValue;

// encode iso to utf8
if (!mb_check_encoding($desc, 'UTF-8')) {
    $desc = mb_convert_encoding($desc, 'UTF-8');
}

echo $desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an escape character so the quotes are treated as text.

```
Try using "&apos;"   for (') and "&quot;" for (")
```

Comment: Yes, it will resolve the issue as you mentioned above. But I want to resolve it with ( ’ ) and ( “ ).

Comment: Where are you getting the test.xml file from?  The special characters should properly escaped otherwise the file is not compliant to the XML standards. If changing the file is not an option, then maybe try escaping it in your code before printing it.

Comment: I added .xml file code in my question as EDIT#2. Please check and provide your feedback.